# Kernel and image of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: Let $m$, $n$ be natural numbers. Suppose $m\mid n$. Define $\theta\colon \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ by $\theta([a]_n)=[a]_m$.

What are the kernel and image of $\theta$?

I know what the general set is for the kernel but the output can never be zero it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. Think of easy examples as $m=2,\ n=4$. 
Then we have $\theta:\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_2$ mapping $[2]_4\mapsto [2]_2=[0]_2$.

Comment: can u give one example of when its zero because I don't understand how congruence classes can just equal 0

Comment: If you take $a=2$ when $m=2$ and $n=4$. That should work?

Comment: so would the $ker/theta$ be [m]_n?

Comment: actually $ker\theta$ would be m right?

Comment: It will be all the congruence classes $[a]$ where $a$ is divisible by $m$.

Comment: How do you write this formally?

Comment: ker(theta)={[r] is an element of Z_n : r=sm for some integer s}